# Dart - Filter list in list which contain at least one element

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to filter a list of games by a list of platforms.

For example, I got this list of games (Game1, Game2, Game3, Game4):

[image]

I want to be able to filter this list to get all PC and MAC games (it must return [Game1, Game2, Game3])

Currently I can filter my list only with one platform ID, but not with a list of platform:

```
var filteredGames = games.where((g) => g.platforms.any((p) => p.id == /*PC or MAC*/)).toList();
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code only, it required just little modifications and you are good to go. Just use [contains()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/String/contains.html) from the list which you will have for checking the list of games platforms

**Algo**

> 1. Maintain a list of platform which will be used to filter
> 2. Check with the `games` whether it has the item present in the `gamesList` or not
> 3. Store in the variable for filtered data

**Answer Code**

```
games.where((game) => game.platforms.any((p) => gamesList.contains(p))).toList();
```

**Example**

```
// this is for maintaining multiple list for check
List<String> gamesList = ['PC', 'MAC'];

var filteredList = games.where((game) => game.platforms.any((p) => gamesList.contains(p))).toList();

print(filteredList); // [Instance of 'Game', Instance of 'Game', Instance of 'Game']

for(var game in filteredList){
  print(game.name);  // Game1, Game2, Game4
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Changed a bit to works with my "platform" object: 

"return games.where((g) => g.platforms.any((p) => platformsId.any((m) => m == p.id))).toList();"

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
List<Game> games = getAllGames();
List<Game> filteredGames = [];
List<String> platformsToFilterBy = ['MAC', 'PC'];
games.where((game) => game.platforms.where((platform) {
   if (platformsToFilterBy.contains(platform.name)) {
      filteredGames.add(game);
   }
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void main() {
  List<Game> games = [
    Game(1, "mario", ["Linux", "Mac", "Windows"]),
    Game(2, "Zelda", ["Mac", "Windows", "Playstation"]),
    Game(3, "Wow", ["Windows"]),
  ];

  var filters = ["Linux", "Playstation"];
  
 
  for (String filter in filters) {
    games.removeWhere((game) =>
        game.platforms.contains(filter)); 
  }

  for (var game in games) {
    print(game.name);
    // Wow
  }
}

class Game {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final List platforms;

  Game(this.id, this.name, this.platforms);
}
```